# how to decode following url in php

Tags: php, json

I'm try to decode following url but i can't get result.

```
{"main_cat":[{"main_cat_id":"1","main_cat_name":"Door"},{"main_cat_id":"2","main_cat_name":"Sunmica"}]}
```

i tried following code, please tell me where i'm doing wrong...

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");
    $response['main_cat'] = array();
    $json = file_get_contents("http://localhost//Project/Fashion/select_main_cat.php");
    $dat["main_cat"] = json_decode($json);
    foreach ($dat["main_cat"] as $key->$val ) {
        ?>
    <td><?php
        echo $dat["main_cat"]->$key;

    ?></td>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Errors:

[image: Error desc]

Comment: Is that the value retrieved from the url? Sorry, I'm a bit unclear whether you're trying to decode the URL or the JSON returned from the URL.

Comment: i'm newbie and i'm learning json encoding and decoding..

Comment: `foreach  ($dat["main_cat"] as $key => $val)`

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: Respected, @War10ck.. yes i'm retrieved values from url, as above i'm just showing result..

Comment: @War10ck, yes wait a minute, i'll show you.

Comment: @War10ck, please check errors..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always provide source code, error messages and other textual information as inline plain text rather than external pictures. Text is searchable, reusable and normally easier to read. (BTW, how comes you're getting an error in line 18 or a 14-line block of code?).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, sure next time i'll keep it in mind. i'm not sure my code is correct or not. please correct me, if i doing wrong. it will helps me.

Comment: Your editor should have a margin with the line number count (if you cannot see it, there's probably a way to enable it). That's what the *on line 18* part of the error message means.

Comment: can you post the correct json value?

Answer (score 0):

Decoding

```
{"main_cat": [{"main_cat_id": "1", "main_cat_name": "Door"}, {"main_cat_id": "2", "main_cat_name": "Sunmica"}]}
```

will give you an object like this

```
$dat = {
  main_cat:
    [
        {
           main_cat_id: 1
           main_cat_name: Door
        },
        {
           main_cat_id: 2
           main_cat_name: Sunmica
        }
    ]
}
```

So you can iterate like this:

```
$dat = json_decode($json);
foreach ($dat["main_cat"] as $key => $val ): ?>
    <td>
        <?php echo $val->main_cat_name; ?>
    </td>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the JSON string you receive is structured like this:

```
"main_cat":
    |
    |--("main_cat_id: 1", "main_cat_name: Door")
    |
    |--("main_cat_id: 2", "main_cat_name: Sunmica")
```

So at the top of this JSON you find the `"main_cat"` object, that contains an array of another 2 objects.

The code to parse all the keys and their relative values can be like this:

```
$dat["main_cat"] = json_decode($json);
foreach ($dat["main_cat"]->main_cat as $cat ) {
    foreach ($cat as $key => $val) {
        ?><td><?php echo $key . ': ' . $val ?></td><?php
    }
}
```